# Update all installed GNOME 3 extensions at once

Tags: shell, gnome3

I use [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) website and [GNOME Shell integration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep) Chrome extension to search and install gnome-shell extensions.

I know that I can use the website and the Chrome extension above to also update the extensions manually one by one.

Is there a way (preferably a shell command) to check and update all the gnome-shell extensions at once instead of updating them manually one by one?

Comment: It might be useful to figure out how the GNOME Shell integration Chrome extension installs the extensions. The GitHub repository of the Chrome extension: https://github.com/GNOME/chrome-gnome-shell

Comment: Extensions are usually hosted on GitHub. It is possible to clone them from there and then later pull to get new changes. There is an issue with this approach because some extensions do not follow the same directory structure and some need to be compiled/built before use. I'm currently using this Makefile to install and update my extensions: https://github.com/curusarn/dotfiles/blob/master/Makefile#L186 It is not an elegant solution but I'm still mentioning it here anyway because of the general lack of tools for updating all gnome extensions at once.